Recommendation on the best laptop for an entry level cybersecurity analyst/ python learner
Out of the following three laptops which is best recommended for the field stated in the title.

Dell latitude 7200 2in1 16GB RAM, 256 SSD Intel Core i7 8th gen
Dell Latitude 7290 convertible Intel Core i5 8th gen, 16GB RAM, 256 SSD
Asus Zenbook Flip 13 UX363ja, 8GB ram(soldered), Intel Core i5 10th gen, SSD 256GB


From those three that you have listed I would recommend the Dell Latitude 7200 for the following reasons. It has 16GB of RAM (8GB can be not enough) and a pretty good CPU. I only would recommend with this model to upgrade the SSD to 512GB or 1TB.
Asus Zenbook I would definitely not recommend because it's soldered on RAM and (almost) impossible to upgrade. 8GB is nowadays enough for basic tasks with Windows 10/11.
The Dell Latitude 7290 I also would not recommend over the Dell latitude 7200, because the CPU is weaker and may bottleneck faster in the near feature.
